# What is a "Supply Llama" in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

For Fortnite Battle Royale, one of my weekly challenges for week one (Free Pass) is to  **Search a Supply Llama**.

Does that mean that there other types of Llamas? The only one I know and only seen is the Loot Llama. Can someone give me a list of these other Llamas? And what is a Supply Llama?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They aren't different.  The Supply Llama is the same thing as what you are calling a Loot Llama.  This is the only llama in the game.

For more information about Supply Llamas, read up on their [wiki page](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Supply_Llama).

Comment: Oh okay. Got me confused when I saw it.

Comment: From my understanding there are also Llamas in the Save The World part of the game that seem to be substantively different in content and acquisition, though I don't know if they have a different name or appearance as well. I don't believe there is any crossover where you could encounter the STW Llamas in BR, or have an STW Llama affect challenge progress in BR.

Comment: Additionally, although probably even less relevant, there is a large Llama structure near Junk Junction (or there was in Season 4, I have not checked in Season 5). If it still exists then I think it wouldn't count for the challenge.

Comment: Ive heard of llamas providing Xp boosts in game. Pretty sure its fake or in STW

Comment: "It's the only llama in the game."  Only if you're talking about Battle Royale mode. All of the Save the World game mode's loot boxes are llamas.